# How to set up fix url in android javascript?

Tags: javascript, android

i have an android app which takes URL from users. i want to fix it to one specific URL regardless what user enters. How can i edit code below to set app url as https://www.example.com

```
public class TakeUrl extends Activity {
    EditText urlET;
    Button submitBtn;
    Locale myLocale;
    String langCode = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.take_url_activity);

        urlET = findViewById(R.id.et_domain_takeUrl);
        submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit_takeUrl);

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String appDomain = urlET.getText().toString();

               getDataFromApi(appDomain);
               Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.appDomain, appDomain);
              
        });
    }
```

Comment: Strange ! i couldn't get even a single answer on stackoverflow?